# The operator date in kendo ui Grid is not getting the kind

Tags: kendo-grid

Good night! I'm going in kendo ui Grid schema model and a field of type date, but that is happening on the filter settings when I click is just showing operators that work with string, looking like he just identidica this field as a string! Can anyone help me?

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){})
            function getData(page)
            {
                data = page.split("||");
                //data = $.parseJSON(page);
                //alert(data.toSource());
                //alert(JSON.parse(page));
                return {data: JSON.parse(data[1]), total: data[0]};
                //return JSON.parse(page);
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {

                 var windowTemplate = kendo.template($("#windowTemplate").html());

                var window = $("#window").kendoWindow({
                   title: "Are you sure you want to delete this record?",
                   visible: false, //the window will not appear before its .open method is called
                   modal: true,
                   resizable: false,
                   draggable: false,
                   width: "400px",
                   height: "200px",
                 }).data("kendoWindow");



                var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        serverSorting: true,
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 3,
                        schema: {
                            data: "data",
                            total: function(e){
                                //alert(e.toSource());
                                return e.total;
                            },
                            model: { id: "id_turma" },
                                    fields: {
                                        id_turma: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        nome_turma: { validation: { required: true } },
                                        sigla_turma: { validation: { required: true, max:12 },
                                        data_criacao: { editable: true,type:"date", format: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
                                    }
                        },
                        transport: {
                            read: function (option) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '<?=$view->encode('ctrl.php?turma=lista_turma');?>',
                                    type: "POST",
                                   data:
                                   {
                                       skip: option.data.skip,
                                       take: option.data.take,
                                       pageSize: option.data.pageSize,
                                       page: option.data.page,
                                       sorting: JSON.stringify(option.data.sort),
                                       filter: JSON.stringify(option.data.filter)
                                   },
                                   success: function (result) {
                                       var data = getData(result);
                                       option.success(data);
                                    },
                                    error: function (err) {
                                        alert(err.toSource());
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    //sortable: true,
                    sortable: {
                        mode: "multiple", // enables multi-column sorting
                        allowUnsort: true
                    },
                    pageable: {
                        refresh: true,
                        pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
                        buttonCount: 2
                    },
                    selectable: true,
                    filterable: true,
                    columnMenu: true,
                    height: 350,
                    groupable: true,
                    toolbar: [{name:"create",text:"Adicionar"}],
                    columns: [
                        { field:"nome_turma", title: "Nome"/*, filterable: false*/ },
                        { field: "sigla_turma", title:"Sigla", width: "100px" },
                        {
                            field: "data_criacao",
                            title: "Date create",
                            type: "date",
                            format: '{0:dd/MM/yyyy}',
                            template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(data_criacao, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd/MM/yyyy') #",
                            filterable: {
                                ui: "datepicker",
                                format: '{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'

                            }
                        },
                        { 
                            command:[
                            {
                                name: "edit",
                                text: { 
                                    edit: "Editar",               // This is the localization for Edit button
                                    update: "Salvar",             // This is the localization for Update button
                                    cancel: "Cancelar"    // This is the localization for Cancel button
                                }
                            },
                            { 
                                //className: "btn-apagar",
                                name: "destroy", 
                                text: "Apagar",
                                click: function(e) {
                                    alert('sdadsdsadsadsa');
                                     var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); //get the row for deletion
                                    var data = this.dataItem(tr); //get the row data so it can be referred later
                                    window.content(windowTemplate(data)); //send the row data object to the template and render it
                                    window.open().center();  

                                    $("#yesButton").click(function(){
                                      grid.dataSource.remove(data)  //prepare a "destroy" request 
                                      grid.dataSource.sync()  //actually send the request (might be ommited if the autoSync option is enabled in the dataSource)
                                       window.close();
                                    })
                                    $("#noButton").click(function(){
                                       window.close();
                                    })                                        
                                }
                            }
                          ]}

                            //{ command: { text: "ManageEvent", click: showDetails }, title: " Edit Event", width: "60px" },
                        ],
                    editable  : {
                        mode : "popup",
                        update: true,
                        destroy: false,
                        template: $("#popup_editor").html(),
                        window : {
                            title: "Edit Office",           // Localization for Edit in the popup window
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code in the read could pass the filter what type of field being sent.

```
read: function(option) {

                    if (option.data.filter !== undefined) {
                      var fields = source.options.schema.model.fields;
                      //alert(option.data.filter.filters.length);
                      for (var i = 0; i < option.data.filter.filters.length; i++) {
                          var name = option.data.filter.filters[i].field;

                          if (fields[name].type === "date") {
                              //Format date
                              option.data.filter.filters[i].value = kendo.toString(option.data.filter.filters[i].value,"yyyy-MM-dd");
                          }
                          //add type at filter get type of schema
                          option.data.filter.filters[i].type = (fields[name].type)?fields[name].type:"string";
                      }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the date field in the schema from the datasource:

```
schema: {
    model: {
        fields: {
            data_criacao: { type: "date" }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that. Normally the datasource is defined first.

Answer (score 0):

I moved to the part of the dataSource follows:

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read: function (option) {
                                 $.ajax({
                                    url: '<?=$view->encode('ctrl.php?turma=lista_turma');?>',
                                    //type: "POST",
                                    //dataType: "json",

                                   data:
                                   {
                                       skip: option.data.skip,
                                       take: option.data.take,
                                       pageSize: option.data.pageSize,
                                       page: option.data.page,
                                       sorting: JSON.stringify(option.data.sort),
                                       filter: JSON.stringify(option.data.filter)
                                   },
                                   success: function (result) {
                                       var data = getData(result);
                                       //var data = getData(result);
                                       option.success(data);
                                    },
                                    error: function (err) {
                                        alert(err.toSource());
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {

                                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        serverSorting: true,
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 3,
                        schema: {
                            data: function(data){
                                return data.data;
                            },
                            total: function(data){
                                return data.total;
                            },
                            model: { 
                                id: "id_turma" ,
                                fields: {
                                    id_turma: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    nome_turma: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    sigla_turma: { validation: { required: true, max:12,  min: 2 }},
                                    data_criacao: { editable: true,type:"date", format: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }),
```